# Typescript: How to Expect Exact Class Instance As Function Parameter

Tags: typescript, class, comparison, instance

## Code

Consider the following code, one base class, two subclasses, and a function taking one instance of one subclass.

```
abstract class AbstractNumberHolder {
    constructor(private readonly value: number) { }
    getValue() { return this.value; }
}

class UserId extends AbstractNumberHolder {
    equals(u: UserId) { return this.getValue() === u.getValue(); }
}

class SubscriptionCost extends AbstractNumberHolder {
    equals(s: SubscriptionCost) { return this.getValue() === s.getValue(); }
}

// ~~~

function printUserId(u: UserId) {
    console.log(u.getValue());
}

// ~~~

const subCost = new SubscriptionCost(50);
const uid = new UserId(1000105);

printUserId(subCost); // DOES NOT ERROR, WHILE IT SHOULD!
```

([Typescript Playground link of the above code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwMbAJIDt0QE4B4AqAfFALxS4AihAFAJSnHUVQRzAToAmAzlPlAH4ozAFzDaAbgBQoSLEQoCxMvGRpMOJVABkfaVIQAjbsGxqoSADYJuvAILHTagHIBXALaGcACQD2lzhwoAG8pKHCLX3QTbFcUX2xqMGwASwA3BHYobAgETijLECgMy1cIMXQPL2x6YKgAXzCIgHMIYAA1BFKIOhDsttdsdChgAAsU7gA6ErKJBqlGqSsbXgBVbhxUThY2Dh4oBxiXKp9-QOwQpvCIAEdXLu5qVzF1zc5a-uBB4bGJydaOl0yr0SKCoK5-m1Ot06HNGotlrYoABlVzGJCpMDAFJRADCvhMO3YXHsjjMKDcnlOASCoQiLDuD2o3DEqPRmOxeIJwA+OS+QxG4ymAOhwPooLIwqhQJ6knmiwAZq50CgccNkil0MBXtgtk8Xhtde9LvSkFFuP4IJNLL5mk9IYCYbQ5QspEtzcAoNw0fjCWQsAB3FFo7gYlJYtW+4DUACsAAZJO7op7XCltv6IEGdXqAIxx-N5mOJqQarXZzjMn3cxNAA))

#### Explanation

I have two totally different classes, `UserId` and `SubscriptionCost` which are representing two totally different concepts.  Since the inner implementation of them are similar for the time being (both holding a number value), I am having them extend a base `AbstractNumberHolder` class.

---

## Problem

The problem is, Typescript [only compares the structure](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#classes) of the classes, and  these two classes have the same structure!  And it sucks...

**It totally negates the reason I decided to pick Typescript in the first place.**  If a developer can accidentally pass a "Subscription Cost" instead of a "User Id" to a function, and typescript cannot catch it, then why should we bother having the types at all?!

---

## Existing Sub-optimal Solutions

I looked around and thought about possible solutions for it.  Below are the solutions that can work, but I wouldn't be happy with any of them.

#### Solution 1) Manually Check Using `instanceof`

Thank God, `instanceof` works as expected!  So, I could have the first line of my `printUserId` be:

```
function printUserId(u: UserId) {
    assert(u instanceof UserId, "Please pass a UserId!");
    console.log(u.getValue());
}
```

Clearly it's not scalable at all, and for every single argument of every single function I need to write one such line!

#### Solution 2) Use `Exact` type on the function

I have found that there are numerous creative (yet, handmade and non-standard) ways that you can enforce a type to be exactly what you want. (comments of [this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), for instance.)

Using that, I can enforce the function to take **exactly** a UserId.

```
type ExactInner<T> = <D>() => (D extends T ? D : D);
type Exact<T> = ExactInner<T> & T;

function printUserId(u: Exact<UserId>) {
    console.log(u.getValue());
}
```

It's much shorter than the first solution, but still I need to remember to put this `Exact<...>` on every single typed argument of every single function in my code!

#### Solution 3) Add Nuance to the Classes

One major setback with the prior solutions is, I need to change the **functions** that use instances of these classes.  And generally speaking, there are more functions in the code than classes.

So, attempting to solve it from a different perspective, I can add a nuance to the classes to make them uninterchangeable!

```
class UserId extends AbstractNumberHolder {
    private I_AM_A_USER_ID = true;
}

class SubscriptionCost extends AbstractNumberHolder {
    private I_AM_A_SUBSCRIPTION_COST = true;
}
```

Again, this solution requires a manual change on each class and looks redundant.  (It also doesn't scale well with classes directly coming from a class factory.)

#### Solution 4) Add Private Nuance at the `extend` time (Flavoring/Branding)

I found this wonderful article at https://michalzalecki.com/nominal-typing-in-typescript/ talking about our issue of nominal typing.  Also, https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/15/typescript-flexible-nominal-typing/ is having a great comparison of two subtle branding methods.

Based on the solutions there, I can think of passing a string (as a fake type) to Parent class and making a nuance/brand/flavor out of it.

```
abstract class AbstractNumberHolder<T extends string> {
    private _?: T;
    constructor(private readonly value: number) { }
    getValue() { return this.value; }
}

class UserId extends AbstractNumberHolder<"UserId"> {
    equals(u: UserId) { return this.getValue() === u.getValue(); }
}

class SubscriptionCost extends AbstractNumberHolder<"SubscriptionCost"> {
    equals(s: SubscriptionCost) { return this.getValue() === s.getValue(); }
}
```

What I like about this solution is the change that I need to make as I add more classes/functions is minimal.  Also, you wouldn't miss the required change (as `T extends string` is not optional).

However, there's still some manual work here.  I wish it could be automated...

---

So, anyone has any better solution for this issue that guarantees no developer is going to accidentally miss (while creating more classes/functions in the future) and doesn't require manual work per class/function?

Comment: PS. Apparently investigating this "nominal typing support" is the second thing on the "future" roadmap of Typescript: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap